# How to initialize Stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a [Bottom Tabs Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator) that contains a [Stack Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator) on each tab.

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator<MainRoutes>();

export interface MainNavProps {
  user: User,
  signOut: SignOut
}

export function MainNav({ user, signOut }: MainNavProps) {

  return (
    <MainNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="DashboardSection" screenOptions={mainScreenOptions}>
      <MainNavigator.Screen name="DashboardSection" component={DashboardStack} options={dashboardOptions} />
      <MainNavigator.Screen name="HashSection" component={HashStack} options={hashesOptions} />
      <MainNavigator.Screen name="AccountSection" component={AccountStack} options={accountOptions} />
    </MainNavigator.Navigator>
  )
}
```

I want to emphasize here the `HashStack` Navigator. It consists of two screens, namely:

```
const HashNavigator = createStackNavigator<HashRoutes>();

const screenOptions = ({ navigation, route }: HashStackProps): StackNavigationOptions => {

    const pressHandler = () => navigation.navigate("Modify", { title: "modify hashes" });

    return {
        ...sectionScreenOptions,
        headerRight: function HeaderLeft() {
            return (
                route.name === "Index" ?
                    <Button
                        marginR-10
                        iconSource={() => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="plus" color={Colors.primaryDarker} size={28} />
                        )}
                        style={{ width: 35, height: 35 }}
                        color={Colors.primaryDarker}
                        outline
                        outlineColor={Colors.primaryDarker}
                        onPress={pressHandler}
                    /> : <></>
            );
        },
        headerTitle: route.params.title
    }
}

export function HashStack() {
   
    return (
        <HashNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="Index" screenOptions={screenOptions} >
            <HashNavigator.Screen name="Index" component={Hash} initialParams={{ title: "hashes overview" }} />
            <HashNavigator.Screen name="Modify" component={ModifyHash} />
        </HashNavigator.Navigator>
    );
}
```

To simplify the explanation I recorded a video:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/56756949/137601978-9d3aec89-3732-42a4-834b-b427bc1f73ca.mp4

When I press the tab `Hashtag`, which is in the middle of the screen it shows the `HashStack` component.
As you can see the `headerRight` property on the `HashStack` `ScreenOptions` is active and it shows a `plus` button. Clicking on the `plus` button it navigates to the `Modify` route within `HashStack`.
Then pressing on the tab `Dashboard`, which is the first `Route` in the `Bottom Tabs Navigator` and  press the `Hashtag` tab again, it does not show the initial route screen, which is:

```
<HashNavigator.Screen name="Index" component={Hash} initialParams={{ title: "hashes overview" }} />
```

The question is, how to reset the `HashNavigator` when another `Bottom Tab` has been pressed so that the `Hashtag` tab always shows the initial route `Index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `unmountOnBlur: true` inside the tab screen options of the `HashStack`

```js
const hashesOptions = {
  // other options
  unmountOnBlur: true
}
export function MainNav({ user, signOut }: MainNavProps) {

  return (
    <MainNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="DashboardSection" screenOptions={mainScreenOptions}>
      <MainNavigator.Screen name="DashboardSection" component={DashboardStack} options={dashboardOptions} />
      <MainNavigator.Screen name="HashSection" component={HashStack} options={hashesOptions} />
      <MainNavigator.Screen name="AccountSection" component={AccountStack} options={accountOptions} />
    </MainNavigator.Navigator>
  )
}
```